# SSD not showing up while installing Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, sata

[SOLVED, See my answer]
In my Laptop, there are two Hard Drives. One is SSD and Another one is HDD.
My windows in installed in SSD from the beginning and working fine.
I am trying to install Linux on SSD.
While installing, the SSD disk is not showing on drive choosing option. Only HDD is showing.
What can I do?
NB:

1. SSD is showing in Disk Management Section.
2. SSD is working properly with windows.
3. HDD Controller Type AHCI, Interface SATA
4. SSD Controller Type NVMe, Interface PCIe

Comment: Make sure when booting the Linux installer to boot into UEFI version of Linux not the old CSM mode. Also make sure the used Linux distro is not too old to know NVMe drives.

Comment: In addition to this ^^^ also make sure you haven't enabled Microsoft proprietary features in Windows like dynamic disks or whatever as they may prevent the drive form being used for other OSes. While at the live section you can open Disks or GParted to check (1) whether or not the drive is recognized and (2) if recognized how does it show up (identifiable partitions vs something else).

Comment: And, of course, disabling Windows Fast Startup feature is a MUST when dual-booting so do that *before* attempting to install other OS.

Comment: Perhaps Linux is not showing that drive as it assume it is all Windows and has to be preserved.

Answer (score 2):

[Solved]

- There is something to be done while using NVMe SSD.
- The SSD must be run on AHCI Mode. Its default mode is usually RAID or IDE mode.
- If this type of problem occurs, we have to convert RAID/IDE mode to AHCI mode.
- I have found a solution in askubuntu. Here is the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127505/ssd-not-detected-during-ubuntu-installation#:%7E:text=Restart%20the%20computer%20and%20enter,automatically%20boot%20to%20Safe%20Mode.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: RAID or AHCI does not apply to NVMe SSDs. It applies only to the chipset’s SATA controller.

Comment: This did the trick on Intel NUC running LInux Mint

Comment: It helps if you accept the answer even if it's the one you provided yourself.

Comment: No need to `SOLVED` it indeed, click the button to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to go to Bios setting and disable Intel Optane Memory setting so my Linux installer can recognize my NVMe SSD.

Answer (score 0):

Having Intel Rapid Storage Technology (RST) enabled in BIOS can also be a source of this problem. Apparently, this is only an issue if Windows was installed on the drive while RST was enabled.
**WARNING**: I do not know if disabling RST will cause issues with the existing Windows partitions. I have seen conflicting information. If you plan to retain access to that data for dual boot or another purpose, ensure you have a good backup.